# OpenSSH - map aliases in ~/.ssh/config to IP addresses in command line

Tags: shell, ssh, networking, openssh

Is it possible to query ~/.ssh/config in the command line? Let's say I would like to retrieve what IP address does the particular alias point to in a separate program, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand that you just want the IP address returned, ie., 192.168.1.1, then this is one (incredibly brittle) way of querying the file from the command line, provided you have the appropriate permissions to read it *and* your `.ssh/config` is consistently formatted:

```
awk '/Host $youralias/ {getline; print $2}' .ssh/config
```

<sup>I am only posting this as I would like to understand how to use `awk` to do this, but my knowledge is, obviously, quite limited.</sup>

Comment: This works only if the order of line is keep. Or I mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you are asking...

Say you have a SSH alias for 'mainserver' so you can do `ssh mainserver`. If you want it to also work for `ping mainserver`, you need to put an alias in `/etc/hosts`, like so:

/etc/hosts:

```
192.168.0.1 comp-one
192.168.0.2 comp-two

192.168.0.20 mainserver
```

Then you could do `ping mainserver` and it would ping 192.168.0.20.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more robust way of retrieving the `HostName` based on `Host` in the `.ssh/config` file.

```
sshalias()
{
    awk "\$1==\"Host\" {host=\$2} \$1==\"HostName\" && host==\"$1\" {print \$2}" "$HOME/.ssh/config"
}
```

function call:

```
sshalias mymachine
172.30.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-G` option to `ssh`:

> `-G`:      Causes `ssh` to print its configuration after evaluating `Host`
> and `Match` blocks and exit.

So for the example, we'd use

```bash
ssh -G $host | awk '$1 == "hostname" { print $2 }'
```

You might need to do name lookup on the result if you really need an IP address rather than a hostname, but I'll assume you know how to do that.

Note that this might not be the actual host to which the outgoing connection is made, if the config uses `ProxyCommand` to connect via a jump host, for example.

Answer (score -1):

The file you mention is a text file, it contains *host names* and possibly *IP addresses* to identify the machines you connect to. Host names can be resolved to IP addresses using the `host(1)` command. The format is quite simple, so it isn't too hard to find out what is in there. Note that wildcards can be used in the file (mine states `*.fedoraproject.org`).