# What is the recommended way to retrieve host and repository from git URL

Tags: ssh, git, url

Think of a utility like [gerrit-sh](https://github.com/shanesmith/gerrit-sh) which uses git config options to determine where the gerrit host is located. The context for my question is [this function get_repo_remote_config()](https://github.com/shanesmith/gerrit-sh/blob/17103b920e418f0335cbd448fff03eb16c536cdd/gerrit#L205). So I want to retrieve the repository and more important the host name of the git URL configured in `.git/config`.

The method assumes you have your username, host, port and repo all inside your git config. Which ignores that you can use ssh aliases.

What is a recommended way to either

1. tell the host and repo for a git URL
2. fetch the antialiased URL based on the git URL which might contain SSH aliases

For (1) I can think of splitting on the first `:` or `/` with some additional magic.

For (2) I could think of something like in [this question: awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62864/openssh-map-aliases-in-ssh-config-to-ip-addresses-in-command-line).

Both approaches would work, but isn't there a more convenient way to do that? Isn't there a utility for some SSH/URL calculation?

Thanks in advance.